# Find email by sender email address - Filter syntax

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

In an Outlook 2010 Add-in, I want to find an item in a folder sent by a given email address:

```
MailItem FindEmailFromSender(MAPIFolder folder, string emailAddress)
{
    string filter = "[sender] = '" + emailAddress + "'"; // This filter is wrong.
    return folder.Items.Find(filter) as MailItem;
}
```

It seems like this should be super easy, but I just cannot find the correct syntax.  What is the correct filter syntax for filtering on sender email address?

Comment: Maybe the property names are case sensitive. Have you tried with `[Sender]`?

Comment: And based on the `MailItem` doc you are probably looking for the property `[SenderEmailAddress]`...

Comment: @nemesv - `[SenderEmailAddress]` does the trick.  Can you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [MailItem documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176688%28v=office.12%29.aspx) you need to use

`[SenderEmailAddress]` for the  e-mail address of the sender

or

`[SenderName]` for the  display name of the sender

You should also note that the property names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for **E-mail Account** property filter. This example worked for me...

```cs
string filter = "[E-mail Account] = '" + emailAddress + "'"; // filters on exact address
return folder.Items.Find(filter) as MailItem;
```

If you want to search by sender name, you can use this:

```cs
string filter = "[From] = '" + senderName + "'"; // filters on exact sender name "Bob Johns"
return folder.Items.Find(filter) as MailItem;
```

Also see [MSDN for item filtering reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb147583%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and this [MSDN blog post describing how to find DASL property names](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2008/12/19/finding-dasl-property-names.aspx) using Advanced Find.

Comment: Nope, `[E-mail account]` doesn't work.  I got mixed results with `[From]`, it worked on one email but not another.  `[SenderEmailAddress]` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to nemesv for the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153937/361684).  I also managed to figure out how to find the sender address when an email is sent "on behalf of" another account thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258609/361684) on another question.  I'm including it here for completeness:

```
MailItem FindEmailSentOnBehalfSender(MAPIFolder folder, string emailAddress)
{
    string filter = "@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F\" = '{0}'";
    return folder.Items.Find(string.Format(filter, emailAddress)) as MailItem;
}
```